# How to append a new row on pandas dataframe with single column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

This question might seems easy but I could not find any solution for it.

Say I have a CSV file like this without headers.

```
121
334
313
930
```

I want to add/append new row with number `0` at the bottom like this

```
121
334
313
930
0
```

I tried with the following method but did not succeed.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

folder_path = "/home/Ling/test/"
df = pd.read_fwf(folder_path + "test1.csv", usecols=[0], delimiter=",")
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0]], dtype=int)
print df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

The result

```
NaN 121
NaN 334
NaN 313
NaN 930
0.0 NaN
```

I am following this [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

I even try to change from `[[0]]` to `[[0,]]` and `[[,0]]` but did not work.
Is there anything that I miss here in the code?

Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#read data frame with header None
df=pd.read_csv("datapath/df.csv",header=None)
df=df.append(pd.Series(np.array([0])),ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Perhaps describe your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can add new row using `loc` and `shape` as well:

```
df.loc[df.shape[0]] = 0
```

Or if you want to use `append`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([0])
df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Finally, when reading `csv` add `header=None` to imply that no column names are included.

Comment: hi @zipa thank you for your answer. I did not quite understand your suggestion using `loc` and `shape` . do I have to write it like `df2 = df.loc[df.shape[0]] ` and `append` it to? By the way, your second suggestion using `append` working great.